# Connect android client with backend app engine module

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, android-asynctask

This question is because most of the information I find is obsolete and the google documentation I have found is not so clear for me.

Thing is I am developing an application with the backend in app engine and I am not sure how to pass the information between client and server, I have done the endpoints of my server logic and everything i find is not so clear.

I wish to make http querys with the info in Json, also I'm not sure how to use the async calls in the client even when I have the client library (from server endpoints) generated. I'm using Android Studio.

Please don't link **obsoletes tutorials**, most of the library or methods they use are deprecated and i'm not sure if is someone developing now for app engine or is better to build a server more traditional.

Thank you all

**Actualization**

Then I finally decided to follow this tutorial:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

Thing is It seems to be the solution but in my case It is not working.

To test in a real device in a LAN with the development server Do yo know if It is necessary some specific configuration else?

More than:

```
appengine {
  httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
}
```

and

```
 .setRootUrl("http://<my-computer-address>:8080/_ah/api/")
```

I mean some kind of Auth or maybe the router blocks??

Thanks

Comment: look up `UrlConnection`

Answer (score 0):

actually, I don't understand clearly your question, but I guess you wanna connect your application to your backend ( API Webservice), right?
When I was a junior developer (Now, I am also a junior, but I have experience), I used HttpClient even thought it was deprecated.
Then I used OkHttpClient, it's ok and didn't have any problem but I think what senior program will do ? Then my friends told me about Retrofit (library), to handle data you can use reactivex.rxjava . You can try to explore base on my flow
Reply if my opinion is wrong or have any confuse. Thanks